# Flutter iOS app size is huge, how to reduce it?

Tags: ios, flutter, size, reduce

I am new to Flutter.
I am using Android Studio to deploy Flutter sample app (default App) to my iPhone (in release mode). Then I check the app size, it is 52.8 MB. That is too big.
Since I don't have an Apple developer account, I cannot generate App Size Report.

How to reduce the flutter App size for iOS?
I read some articles and have no idea.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing_your_app_s_size/doing_basic_optimization_to_reduce_your_app_s_size

Is there anybody know? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you run ```flutter clean``` command before building the apk?

Comment: I ran "flutter clean", the size is 52.7MB. no difference.